# Stacktrace shows funcion call that is not directly present in failing method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website used by several person and only one person experiences a bug with a strange stacktrace :

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid datetime. at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider) at EditMandate.getFormData()`.

The strange thing is that there is no parse in the function `getFormData`. This function uses functions which uses `DateTime.Parse` but it doesn't use it directly.

Why stack trace shows function that is not directly called by my method?

Also, there is nothing strange in the string  being parse as it worked several times and randomly crashed !

Comment: whats the code in the line of code that causes this? What are the contents of the string when that exception is thrown?

Comment: _"This function uses functions which uses DateTime.Parse but it doesn't use it directly"_ then that's the reason. JIT compiler will **inline function calls**. Why it crashes is another story, you should log which string fails to be parsed...

Comment: I guess that there is a cast missing somewhere where the string should be converted to dateTime...

Comment: This sounds like a globalization issue...

Comment: Regardless of the cause, surrounding the code with try/catch will prevent crashes.

Comment: I've edited your post to ask about one thing (stack trace). If still necessary please *ask separate question* about parsing the value. Feel free to revert/improve my edit if you disagree with it.

Comment: Also using the TryParse method for type conversions is a much safer bet. Never trust that data is in the correct format if it comes from a user's input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that:

- The reason for the problem is due to some broken culture-specific settings on the one person's machine, e.g. a culture which uses an invalid `DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern`
- The reason the direct stack frame isn't showing is that the JIT is inlining the method which calls `DateTime.Parse`

Try to find anything which modifies cultures, or anything "different" about this person's machine.

Comment: +1. I've edited the post to be mainly about the stack trace. Consider updating answer if OP agrees with my change.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem arises with just one user, it's probably that person's culture settings on its local machine.
Check if his settings have something weird (different date and time separators, 24H or 12H format and so on) and try to always standardize the datetime string you recieve from the client before parsing it.